How can I set the values of dropdown list elements programmatically in SharePoint 2019, on- prem, list-new form without workflow?
How can I set the value of 'DRStatus' dropdown list item in code (SharePoint 2019 on-prem) without using workflow?
the code (HTML)
<tr style="visibility: hidden;">
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">DStatus</td>
                                                                                                                                                               
       <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id ="ff32{$Pos}" ControlMode = "New"       FieldName="DRStatus" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff32',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@DRStatus')}"/>
                                                            
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id = "ff32description{$Pos}" FieldName="DRStatus" ControlMode="New"/>
        
</td>
</tr> 

I have tried to do so using JS but it doesn't work!
 var status = $('#Lookup id');
       var statusOption = status.find('option:eq(1)');
       var selectedStatus;          
       selectedStatus= statusOption.text(); 
       alert("DRStatus: " +selectedStatus);
        
       $("input[Title='DRStatus']").val(selectedStatus);

